# Why strcpy from Microsoft supports overlapped copying and bringing potential leak risk?

Tags: c++, c

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;

char * my_strcpy(char *dst,const char *src)
{
    assert(dst != NULL);
    assert(src != NULL);
    char *ret = dst;
    while((* dst++ = * src++) != '\0');
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    char str[4]="abc";
    cout<<str<<endl;
    strcpy(str+1,str); //works, "aabc" will be in it, \0 is out of its range
    cout<<str<<endl;
    my_strcpy(str+1,str); //an error will be occured here as expected
    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

My question is that why strcpy from Microsoft supports overlapped copying and bringing potential leak risk even thought c++ standard library declared strcpy is not supporting overlapped scenario? is there any advantage from this design?

Thanks!

Comment: "even thought c++ standard library declared strcpy is not supporting overlapped scenario" - citation needed.

Comment: "works, and obviously str array now have 5 elem including \0" no, how do you figure?

Comment: I must be missing something here but how does your `my_strcpy` prevent the overlap issues?

Comment: These calls `strcpy(str+1,str);` and `my_strcpy(str+1,str);` **both** provoke undefined behaviour as they are **both** accessing the character array `str` **out** of its bounds.

Comment: Well strcpy, [as defined by the opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/strcpy.html) says: If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: "Hey, I bought this milk that expired 2 weeks ago, but I just drank it and it tasted good. Why did the cow produce such a resilient milk, and bringing potential leak risk, even though the Food and Drug Administration forbids the milk from being still good past the expiration date?" That's exactly how your question sounds.

Comment: Try `strcpy(str+2,str);`.

Comment: The risk comes from improper use of functions. `strcpy` should not be used for overlapping arguments.

Comment: While "working when it shouldn't" certainly falls within the bounds of "undefined behaviour", the practice of silently working around programmer errors impedes portability and ties your (buggy) program to a specific vendor.

Comment: cout<<str<<endl; this statement outputs aabc, it looks like str array is implicitly increased its capacity, it should have not, the \0 element will out of its range, which is leak, potential risk here. i was commenting incorrect before, changed it

Comment: @RossWang Where do you find a guarantee that this will be the output?  You've overwritten the end of the array, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @chill There's no fundamental difference in Microsoft's behavior and his.  Microsoft also states quite clearly that this is undefined behavior.  There's no guarantee that his will crash, and there's no guarantee that Microsoft's won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Microsoft developers simply decided not to insert any checks. The standard does not say that it has to abort when users attempt an overlapping copy. This means it's cheaper to not do the check, and thus it is not done.

C standard libraries often favor performance over anything else...

But you could try compiling your program with [run-time checks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/162azb0k.aspx) enabled. This inserts additional precondition checks into standard library functions and data structures, and might detect such issues.

See also this MSDN article: [Safe Libraries: Standard C++ Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985872%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: His code doesn't have any checks, either.  His code is undefined behavior as well, and if it causes the program to crash, then it's just by chance.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that the Microsoft version is working.
According to their documentation: "The behavior of strcpy is
undefined if the source and destination strings overlap." Your
code doesn't do any error checking in this regard either, and
may end up with undefined behavior if the strings overlap.
Microsoft might even use more or less the same algorithm as you
do (hopefully more cleanly written), and it's pure chance that
one "works" and the other doesn't.  Or they do some sort of
optimization in which they first determine the string length,
before copying.  (If you know the length up front, and the
addresses are aligned, it's possible to copy more quickly by
copying words, rather than bytes.)

Comment: i am not saying my way is better, my version is just following the standard declaration and will throw exception when there is overlap between the 2 arguments in runtime, so calling my version will crash the program, while Microsoft version is letting the copying happen, it may be implemented using some mechanism like memmove but with optimization. i agree it is my job to guarantee the input paras are not overlapped when i am about to use strcpy, just wanna know the design purpose.

Comment: @RossWang: If you change the order of the calls to libc's strcpy and and your's the program most probably wont't crash when using your function but when using the libc's one.

Comment: @alk Maybe.  That was my first reaction as well.  But if you look closely, you'll find that his version (and most of the versions I've used in the past) will overwrite the `'\0'` character before reading it, which means that he won't stop copying until he encounters a memory fault. (Although this depends somewhat on the optimizer---the signature of the standard function is `strcpy( char * restrict, char const* restrict )`, which allows the compiler to assume that it doesn't, and e.g. unwind the loop somewhat, perhaps reading the `'\0'` before it is written.)

Comment: @RossWang First, your way doesn't respect the standard signature, since it doesn't declare the pointers `restrict`.  (Formally, of course, the C++ versions won't use `restrict`, because the keyword doesn't exist in C++.  But practically, all C++ implementations will call the C implementation, where the compiler will have seen the `restrict`.)  And in practice, it's more by chance than anything else that your code causes the program to crash.  Used on a different system, or in different contexts, it could have all sorts of different behavior.  Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @James Kanze, agreed, thank you, as i said, i am always taking care of the source and destination arrays before calling strcpy, we can not rely on undefined behavior to achieve expected result.